# Timeout application-level join in mongoose with express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a timeout with my application-level join between two documents : Thread and Message.

I am trying to *get all the Messages of my Thread* with this code:

```
router.get('/:themeId/threads/:threadId/messages', function(req, res, next) {
  Thread.findById(req.params.threadId, function(err, thread) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    Message.find({ _id: { $in: thread.messages } }), function(err, message) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(message);
    }
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, I got a timeout with my request which I tested Postman.
I had this message when I tested it:

> Could not get any response
>
> There was an error connecting to
>   http://localhost:3000/api/themes/5b1bb59d4210c50cf798da57/threads/5b1bb5e84210c50cf798da59/messages.

Also I checked that `thread.messages` is an array with another request:

*GET http://localhost:3000/api/themes/5b1bb59d4210c50cf798da57/threads/5b1bb5e84210c50cf798da59* :

The result is below and from my `Thread`document :

```
{
    "numberOfViews": 0,
    "numberOfComments": 0,
    "numberOfLikes": 0,
    "numberOfThanks": 0,
    "messages": [
        "5b1bb5ad4210c50cf798da58",
        "5b1bb6464210c50cf798da5a"
    ],
    "_id": "5b1bb5e84210c50cf798da59",
    "theme": "5b1bb59d4210c50cf798da57",
    "title": "Title azerty",
    "createdAt": "2018-06-09T11:11:36.358Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-06-09T11:13:41.062Z",
    "__v": 1
}
```

From my understanding, my request should do a *find Message in my array of Thread.messages*...
But it seems I miss something.

Any idea to solve my timeout request?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You have long DB request, don't you? What answer do you expect?

Comment: Yes, it's caused by the id of MongoDB. I expect any hint to solve my timeout issue.

Comment: What issue? It's unclear what you're asking. How long is this request? Do you have problems with timeout in general or with Postman? Does `function(err, message)` callback trigger at all?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions to try out:

1. Make sure thread.messages is not an empty array. You can do this by asserting that its length is greater than 0.
2. In the clause Message.find({ _id: { $in: thread.messages } }), cast the string values to objectids by before sending it to the find clause. So you can do

```js
var myobj1 = [];

thread.messages.forEach(element => {myobj1.push(Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(element)})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with the ***populate*** of Mongoose and theses sources :

1. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html
2. https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/

Below the modified code:

```
    router.get('/:themeId/threads/:threadId/messages', function(req, res, next) {
      Thread.findById(req.params.threadId, function(err, thread) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        Message.find({_id: { $in : thread.messages } } )
          .populate('messages')
          .exec(function(error, messages) {
            res.json(messages);
          });
      });
    });
```